# Need ComboBoxCellEditor multi selection functionality in SWT

Tags: combobox, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgJ2U.png)I am using treeviewer, in this viewer using comboBoxCellEditor.i want to multiSelection functionality in comboBoxCellEditor. Please suggest.

```
  ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList  ("WINDOWS_WEB","WINDOWS_NONWEB","ANDROID_NATIVE","ANDROID_WEB"));
  editor = new ComboBoxViewerCellEditor(this.viewer.getTree(), SWT.READ_ONLY);
  editor.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
  editor.setInput(arrList);
```

Comment: Combos don't support multiple select. You could perhaps use a `DialogCellEditor` with a check box table.

Comment: Hi, thanks for suggession. actually i want to multiselection option ComboBoxViewerCellEditor. please find the image for your references.

Comment: As I already said you can't do this. ComboBoxViewerCellEditor uses a Combo or CCombo and they don't support multiple selection. You will have to use something else.

Comment: Can you suggest what is the best way to use DialogCellEditor  for multi selection.